# Lukas Kanade optical flow: Understanding the math

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, object-recognition

I found a Matlab implementation of the LKT algorithm [here](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48744-lucas-kanade-tutorial-example-1/content/LucasKanadeExample1/html/LKExample1.html) and it is based on the brightness constancy equation.

The algorithm calculates the Image gradients in x and y direction by convolving the image with appropriate 2x2 horizontal and vertical edge gradient operators.

The brightness constancy equation in the classic literature has on its right hand side the difference between two successive frames.

However, in the implementation referred to by the aforementioned link, the right hand side is the difference of convolution.

```
It_m = conv2(im1,[1,1;1,1]) + conv2(im2,[-1,-1;-1,-1]);
```

Why couldn't It_m be simply calculated as:

```
it_m = im1 - im2;
```

Comment: It'll take you  a minute to verify that `conv2(x,[1,1;1,1])` is different than `x`.

Comment: Are you referring to this line?

It_m = conv2(im1, ones(2), 'valid') + conv2(im2, -ones(2), 'valid'); 

Note that this is just a 2D spatial smoother and ensures that the resulting It_m has the same size as Ix_m and Iy_m matrices (because they are processed with conv2 with a 2x2 kernel and "valid" option).

Comment: @MBaz I don't think his confusion is about conv2(x,[1,1;1,1]) being different than x. I suspect the question is why use that convolution at all and not just compute the time derivative pixel-by-pixel over the two image frames.

Comment: @AtulIngle You're probably right.

Comment: @Raj You would receive a better response if you post this question on StackOverflow with the `matlab` and `image processing` tags

Comment: @Atul, Exactly that. Why not compute pixel by pixel difference?

Comment: @Raj As I said in my comment above, it provides some spatial smoothing and compatible matrix sizes. In theory, there is nothing wrong with im1-im2.

Comment: @Atul, Could you please submit your assessment as a regular answer so that I may accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Comments converted to an answer.)

In theory, there is nothing wrong with taking a pixel-wise difference:

```
Im_t = im1-im2;
```

to compute the time derivative. Using a spatial smoother when computing the time derivative mitigates the effect of noise.

Moreover, looking at the way that [code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48744-lucas-kanade-tutorial-example-1/content/LucasKanadeExample1/html/LKExample1.html) computes spatial (x and y) derivatives:

`Ix_m = conv2(im1,[-1 1; -1 1], 'valid');`

computing the time derivate with a similar kernel and the `valid` option ensures the matrices `It_x`, `It_y` and `Im_t` have compatible sizes.

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, in theory only pixel by pixel difference is stated for optical flow computation. 
However, in practice, all natural (not synthetic) images contain some degree of noise. On the other hand, differentiating is some kind of high pass filter and would stress (high pass) noise ratio to the signal.
Therefore, to avoid artifact caused by noise, usually an image smoothing (or low pass filtering) is carried out prior to any image differentiating (we have such process in edge detection too). The code does exactly this, i.e. apply and moving average filter on the image to reduce noise effect.

```
It_m = conv2(im1,[1,1;1,1]) + conv2(im2,[-1,-1;-1,-1]);
```

Comment: Thank you MimSaad for the clarity on filtering topics. Upvoted your answer.

Comment: I'm glad it helped!

Comment: noise reduction is important, but even if you have a totally noise free image then 2 pixel differences will give errors in the final optical flow output. See my answer below for more details

Answer (score 0):

The temporal partial derivative(along t), is connected to the spatial partial derivatives (along x and y).

Think of the video sequence you are analyzing as a volume, spatio-temporal volume. At any given point (x,y,t), if you want to estimate partial derivatives, i.e. estimate the 3D gradient at that point, then you will benefit from having 3 filters that have the same kernel support.

For more theory on why this should be so, look up the topic steerable filters, or better yet look up the fundamental concept of what partial derivative is supposed to be, and how it connects to directional derivatives.

Often, the 2D gradient is estimated first, and then people tend to think of the temporal derivative secondly as independent of the x and y component. This can, and very often do, lead to numerical errors in the final optical flow calculations. The common way to deal with those errors is to do a forward and backward flow estimation, and combine the results in the end.

One way to think of the gradient that you are estimating is that it has a support region that is 3D. The smallest size of such a region should be 2x2x2.

if you do 2D gradients in the first and second image both using only 2x2 filters, then the corresponding FIR filter for the 3D volume is collected by averaging the results of the two filters.

The fact that you should have the same filter support region in 2D is clear to most: thats why the Sobel and Scharr operators look the way they do.

You can see the sort of results you get from having sanely designed differential operators for optical flow in this [Matlab toolbox that I made](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44400-tutorial-and-toolbox-on-real-time-optical-flow), in part to show this particular point.