# Spatial derivative in Lucas-Kanade algorithm

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, derivative, opticalflow

Implementing the Lucas-Kanade algorithm, I got stuck in finding the spatial derivative of images.
In my implementation I’m finding it by this formula:

I<sub>*x*</sub>(i, j) = I(i + 1, j) - I(i - 1, j), I<sub>*y*</sub>(i, j) = I(i, j + 1) - I(i, j - 1)

[image: equation]

The result is very noisy and doesn't seem to be right:

[image: the result of algorithm]

I see the realization in MATLAB with `conv2`, but I can't understand how to calculate spatial derivative with convolution.

Maybe somebody know open source realization of this `conv2` or some other way to calculate this?

Also I’m open to any other cons of my implementation.

My realization: https://github.com/bhankey/TRSPK-2/tree/main/LucasKanade

Comment: Please read [mre], then [edit] your question accordingly. Note that questions must be self-contained. Questions that depend on external links would become meaningless when that link breaks (which happens very often).

Comment: convolution? convolution with a sobel filter, or, since sobel is a derivative convolved with a gaussian, just the derivative kernel, which could be [+1 0 -1], which is _exactly_ your formula (give or take a factor)

Comment: In addition to "the Direction Vector question" in the *Related* post column, did you notice [Lukas Kanade optical flow: Understanding the math](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42044312)?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, but if convolution is exactly what I wrote how can I get rid of noise on the image?

Comment: I haven't counted the lines of code but judging by the number of files it's more than I'm prepared to sift through. I have no idea how you made that picture with the red scribbles on it. nor do I understand what you call "noise". you probably refer to some intermediate result but I don't see any of that. -- you need to *focus* your question. if you have an issue with image gradients, leave all the optical flow stuff out of it.